# Login app with Redux & ReactRouter

Tags: redux, react-router

I would be thankful if someone could point me into a right direction in understanding the Redux architecture.

I should implement "reducer" functions that will handle my actions.
Reducer functions should be combined and create a store.

Lets say I have a LoginForm (React) component, that makes a XHR request to backend API, and receives a JWT token in response.

When I get the response from the API I should dispatch an action like:

```
store.dispatch({type: "USER_LOGGED_IN",
                payload: {username: "john", JWT: "..."});
```

This updates the state of my application.

What next?

How do I route to to next page? How do I rerender my components (like navbar, etc.) with the logged in username?

Do I use listeners for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've a method to authorize user:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// ...

function promisedApiCall(inputData) {
    // ...
    // api request to backend with input data
    // return a promise
}

/*
 * on form submit we call this with input data
 */
function authorizeUser(inputData) {
   return promisedApiCall(inputData)
       .then((response) => store.dispatch({
           type: "USER_LOGGED_IN",
           payload: {
               username: response.userName,
               JWT: response.JWT
           }
       }))
       .then(() => browserHistory.push('/success/path/url'))
       .catch(() => browserHistory.push('/failure/path/url'));
}
```

Assuming you have the following **prerequisites**:

- Created redux store and `store` object is available in the scope where `authorizeUser()` is executed.
- The method `promisedApiCall` is the function which makes the request to backend with input data from `LoginForm`.
- `promisedApiCall` should return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). **[this is really important]**
- Configured [react-router with redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html#)

Once this is complete, app state is updated with user info and also user will be redirected to a new page. This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863577/5069226) explains more about programmatically redirecting using `react-router`.

Access you app state in you component using [Redux **connect**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Now you have the user info in your component as props.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router` has a component `browserHistory`.You can import that like this,

`import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';`

And to change your route,

`browserHistory.push(<route_where_you want_to_go>);`

This will let you change the route.

Comment: yes this is clear for me. It is not clear how were should I place this snippet? How does my application react to state change?